# Algorithm Complexity: Time and Space

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, space-complexity

I have two solutions to one coding problem. Both of the solutions work fine. I just need to find the **time/space** complexity for both of them.

**Question:** Given a string or words, return the largest set of unique words in the given string that are anagrams of each other.

```
Example:
Input: 'I am bored and robed, nad derob'
Correct output: {bored, robed, derob}
Wrong output: {and, nad}
```

**Solution 1:**
In the first solution, I iterate over the given string of words, take each word, sort the characters in it, add it to a dictionary as a key. And the original word (not sorted) is being added to a set of words as a value for that key. Sort helps figure out the words that are anagrams of each other. At each iteration, I also keep track of the key that has the longest set of words as its value. At the end, I return the key that has the longest set.

**Solution 2:**
In the second solution, I do almost the same. The only difference is that I calculate a prime factor for each word to use it as a key in my dictionary. In other words, I don't sort the characters of the word.

```
def solution_two(string):
    primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47,
              53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101]
    d = defaultdict(set)
    longest_set = ''
    for word in string.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").split():
        key = 1
        for ch in word:
            key *= primes[ord(ch.lower()) - 97]
        d[key].add(word)
        if len(d[key]) > len(d[longest_set ]):
            longest_set = key
    return d[longest_set]
```

**My thoughts:**

I think that the runtime of the first solution is O(n), where n is the number of words in the string. **But** if I sort each word of the string, wouldn't it make the runtime O(n) * O(n log n)?

As for the second one, I think that it has the linear runtime too. **But** I have the second loop inside the first one where I iterate through each character of a word...

I am also confused about the space complexity for both of the solutions.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So in the first case i believe that you are correct it is O(n) and sorting the single words should take O(avgwordlengt) and space O(avgwordlenght) if we use counting sort so we have O(n)*O(avgwlenght) time and O(avgwordlenght)*O(n) space but if we use another sorting method then time is O(n)*O(avgwlenght*log(awl)) but save space O(n) in the second case i think you are doing approx the same thing but using your own code

Comment: I think, Python uses Tim sort, it has O(n log n) runtime and space O(n) in worst cases. In this case, should the runtime for the first solution be: O(n)*O(avgwlength*log(awl)) and space O(n) (for keeping all the words in the dictionary) + O(awl) (for sorting each word)?

Comment: So time is O(n)* O(awl log(awl)) and space O(n)*O(awl) but be careful because this looks pretty good but you need to consider that if awl is much smaller than n you get an ~O(n) time while if your awl is bigger you get an O(awl log(awl)) meanwhile worst case of all is if n=awl

Comment: Could you please explain why space is O(n)*O(awl)? We use O(n) for the dictionary, plus each time we sort a word, we take O(awl). Shouldn't it be O(n) + O(awl)? We sort one word at a time.

Comment: As you said EACH time we sort a word we use O(awl) so O(n)*O(awl) + O(n) i just left out the minor O(n)

Comment: So, we have O(n)*O(awl) for sorting + O(n) for keeping the words in the dictionary?

Comment: And in the second solution, I calculate the prime factor for each word. What runtime would that be? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Did I understand correctly that the runtime for the 2nd solution is O(n) (for iterating the string) * O(awl)*O(sqrt(number to be fact)) (for calculating the prime factor of a word)? And what does 'number to be fact' mean? And the space for the 2nd solution is O(n) (for keeping everything in the dictionary)?

Comment: Sorry again, you saying prime factors took me on the wrong path, you just multiply key times a prime number chosen through the char, so the solution in time is O(n)*O(awl) and space is O(n)+ O(prime number count) which i see is 26 so O(1)

Comment: So if i am correct your second algorithm in the WC has a complexity of n² better than the other one!

Comment: So for the second solution I have: time O(n)*O(awl), where O(n) is for iterating the given string and O(awl) is calculating the prime factor for each word (i.e. I take a word, find a prime for each char in the word in the list primes and multiply them). Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused again.. Why is it n^2? It was O(n)*O(awl)?

Comment: Your worst case is if n=awl which gives you n*n otherwise if  n>>awl you have O(n)   and finally if awl>>n O(awl)

Answer (score 0):

ALG1= time is O(n)* O(awl log(awl)) and space O(n)*O(awl) but be careful because this looks pretty good but you need to consider that if awl is much smaller than n you get an ~O(n) time while if your awl is bigger you get an O(awl log(awl)) meanwhile worst case of all is if n=awl –
ALG2= time O(n)*O(awl), where O(n) is for iterating the given string and O(awl) is calculating the prime factor for each word (i.e. I take a word, find a prime for each char in the word in the list primes and multiply them) and space O(n)
same considerations on n and awl as the previous algorithm

So if i am correct your second algorithm in the WC has a complexity of n² better than the other one also in space!

Just to recap :)

Comment: Thank you for the recap, really helpful. I have 2 questions, though:
1. The space complexity for the 2nd ALGO is O(n), right? I guess by 'same considerations on n and awl as the previous algorithm' you meant for the runtime of the 2nd algorithm and not space, right?
2. Sorry, I still can't get this: "your second algorithm in the WC has a complexity of n² better than the other one also in space!" I can understand that the 2nd algo is better in space, but how can it be better in time if in WC it's n^2?

Comment: By the way, in the question there is this precondition about the space complexity: "assume that x >> y where x is the number of words in the given string and y is the number of characters in the longest word". Does it change the above analysis?

Comment: yes as i'm saying if x>> y then both time complexities are both O(n) bc you can consider awl constant so O(n)*O(1). WC is awl=n so you substitute awl with n O(n)*O(n)=O(n^2), if you do the same with the first alg WC is awl=n so O(n^2logn)